# Modifying elements in AbstractTrees.PreOrderDFS/Leaves in Julia does not update the original data structure

Tags: tree, julia

I am working with Julia and using the **`AbstractTrees`** package to traverse a tree structure using **`PreOrderDFS/Leaves`**. My goal is to modify the elements of the tree as I traverse it. However, I've noticed that modifying the **`node`** within the loop doesn't seem to update the original data structure (**`mainexp`** in my case) but modifying node.args[] if node is Expr modifies the **`node`**. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
using AbstractTrees

mainexp = :(a + b * c)

for node in AbstractTrees.PreOrderDFS(mainexp)
    # Modifying the node itself doesn't affect mainexp
    # SomeOperation(node)
    
    # Modifying node.args does affect mainexp
    if isa(node, Expression)
        # SomeModification(node.args)
    end
end

println(mainexp)  # mainexp remains unchanged
```

After this loop, I expected **`mainexp`** to reflect the changes made to the nodes during the traversal, but it seems that the original data structure is not being updated.

Is there a way to achieve this in Julia? Am I missing something in the way I'm using **`AbstractTrees`** or the way I'm modifying the nodes? I would appreciate any insights or examples that demonstrate how to modify the original tree structure while traversing it.

I tried tracking the indices and storing them in a Vector{Any} using this function:

```
cachedtraverseexptree() = begin
  local orderidx = 1
  function traverseexptree(currexptree::Expr, treeidxs::Vector{Any}, parentidx::Int)
    append!(treeidxs, Vector{Any}(undef, length(currexptree.args)))
    for (j,arg) in enumerate(currexptree.args)
      orderidx = orderidx + 1
      treeidxs[orderidx] = [deepcopy(treeidxs[parentidx]); j]
      if isa(arg, Expr)
        traverseexptree(arg, treeidxs, orderidx)
      end
    end
    return treeidxs
  end 
end
```

I am creating the expression for node(`like mainexp.args[9].args[2].args[3]`) using function:

```
function exptreenode(orderidx::Vector{Any})
  nodeexp = "exps"
  for idx in orderidx
    nodeexp = string(nodeexp, ".args[$idx]")
  end
  nodeexp = Meta.parse(nodeexp)
  return nodeexp
end
```

I made the mainexp variable global in module for the output of this function to eval() to the mainexp node. I am getting the node of mainexp if i use `eval(exptreenode(orderidx))`. But how should I modify the node of mainexp(refer: [Modifying an Indexed Value in a Vector Stored as an Expression in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77540621/modifying-an-indexed-value-in-a-vector-stored-as-an-expression-in-julia)).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`node = whatever` always assigns to the variable `node` and never updates the original. The right way to do this would be something like the following, which updates the original node in-place.

```
...
if isa(node, Expr)
    new_ex = :(...) # some other expr
    for fieldname in fieldnames(typeof(new_ex))
        setfield!(node, fieldname, getfield(new_ex, fieldname))
    end
end
...
```

Comment: I am getting following error if I use fieldnames function on Expr: ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fieldnames(::Expr)

Comment: Sorry, should have been `fieldnames(typeof(new_ex))`

Comment: This works if node that we are modifying is of type Expr. What if the node is of type Symbol and we want to modify the symbol name.

Comment: You will need to track the indices as you iterate then.

Comment: I tried tracking indices and found a way to access while traversing the expression tree but I couldn't able to modify node of expresssion tree.