# Modifying an Indexed Value in a Vector Stored as an Expression in Julia

Tags: julia, eval

I have a Julia vector **`a`** defined as follows:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I also have an expression **`exp`** stored, which represents the indexing of the second element in vector **`a`**:

```
exp = :(a[2])
```

Now, I would like to modify the value at the indexed position, i.e., set **`a[2]`** to a new value, say **`4`**. However, I am struggling to find the right syntax or method to achieve this.

I've attempted the usual assignment, but it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
$exp = 4 # This results in an error
```

I've also tried using **`eval`**, but it doesn't seem to update the vector **`a`**:

```
eval(exp) = 4 # This doesn't update the vector a
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to correctly modify the indexed value in the vector **`a`** when the index is stored as an expression? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` an expression using the first one and make there the update.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
ex = :(a[2])
eval(:($ex = 4))

a
#3-element Vector{Int64}:
# 1
# 4
# 3
```

Comment: What if a is not a global variable?

Comment: Can you give an example for this case?